# Can I comment with my Facebook profile on a Stack Overflow question to avoid increasing the comment thread?

Tags: support, comments

I am somehow blocked from chatting on Stack Overflow because my account was previously deleted. A user needs my help, and I can't unnecessarily keep extending the comment thread on their question.

Can I give them my Facebook profile on comments so that they can contact me further?

Comment: Can, technically? Sure. Should? Maybe not. Have you tried solving the root problem with moderators?

Comment: *"a user needs my help"* - are they shining your logo into the sky?

Comment: This belongs in your profile. If someone wants to have a personal relationship (?!) with you, they will look in your profile. It *does not belong* in the comments, under any circumstances. No personal information does.

Answer (score 8):

You're [supporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38903968/another-user-can-login-without-existing-user-logout/38904066#comment65168244_38904066) a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).

Don't do that.

If you want to offer one-on-one consulting, just provide a user with your contact details and leave it off the site. You did that, so that's that.